# Two different project in one git repo

Tags: linux, git, github, repository

I'm fairly new to GIT and I'm trying to figure out if I can do as follow,

I'm developing an app which has a front-end and a back-end.

Let's say the front-end contains 10 files located in this path.

Eg:

```
/home/front_end/file1 , /home/front_end/file2 ...... /home/front_end/file10
```

While, the back-end contains 100 files located in a different path.

Eg:

```
/home/app/code/file1, /home/app/code/file2 ,................./home/app/code/file99
```

How can I create a repo which has two different locations?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really.

What you can do is:

- setting up a repo wherever you want, with '`front_end`' and '`app_code`' folders in it
- symlink `/home/font_end` to `yourRepo/front_end`
  (as in `ln -s /path/to/yourRepo/font_end /home/front_end`)
- symlink `/home/app/code` to `yourRepo/app_code`
  (as in `ln -s /path/to/yourRepo/app_code /home/app/code`)